# gcore not capturing mem image properly

Tags: c, gdb, coredump

Please clarify ..

I have a multithreaded 64-bit C process running on a sun10 server. It is occupying 2.2 GB of RAM.

When I take the gcore and debug it, it shows me "no symbol table" on GDB prompt. Hence I am not able to debug anything.

The binary is not stripped and compiled with the `-g gcc` option. The gcore if of 32 bits.

Why the process image is not showing any symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to start gdb with both executable file and core dump file?

```
gdb executable core
```

This will load symbols from executable and memory dump from core.

As said in gdb manual,

> Traditionally, core files contain only some parts of the address space of the process that generated them.